# How can I load some JavaScript inside of a popup?

Tags: 2013, javascript, calendar, modal-dialog

When creating a new event in our calendar, an absolutely positioned iframe appears. How can I load JavaScript inside this iframe? I want to do some manipulation of the form with JavaScript.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

- Go to the **NewForm** page, for instance:

http://AAA/sites/Site1/Lists/Mylist/**NewForm.aspx**

- Add the parameter for editing the page:

http://AAA/sites/Site1/Lists/Mylist/NewForm.aspx**?toolpaneview=2**

- Insert a CEWP (content editor web part). Inside this webpart you can add JavaScript or reference to a file (reference is best option).

Hope it will be helpfully!